# How to wrap html attributes in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

As in Visual Studio Code with html.format.wrapAttributes = "auto", I would like to automatically wrap the html attributes per lines on saving.

For example, this:

```
<div class="mt-1">
  <span class="form-alert-label" *ngIf="displayMessage.address">
    {{displayMessage.address | translate}}
  </span>
</div>
```

will become:

```
<div class="mt-1">
  <span class="form-alert-label" 
        *ngIf="displayMessage.address">
    {{displayMessage.address | translate}}
  </span>
</div>
```

I guess it's not something built-in in Visual Studio, but there is probably an extension which can do that, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Resharper Extension](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) could realize your needs. But it is a paid extension and new users have 30 days for free use.

It shows that [it could wrap HTML attributes from this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Code_Style_HTML.html#ws_html_settings_editor_code_other).

If this does not meet your requirements, you should [suggest your idea to the DC Forum](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=8).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's too bad that this version is available in VS Code but not VS. I'm looking for a free options, but thanks :). I sent a request to the forum.

Comment: Actually, `we cannot get this so far and cannot get any tips currently and I suggest you could accept this answer to tell other community members this is s feature request`.  And you can share the request here so that anyone who is interested in it including us will vote it so that it will raise more Microsoft's attention to help get what you want as soon as possible.

Comment: Here is the link for people who wants to follow the status: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Wrap-Html-Attribute-en-VS-2019/1305882?entry=suggestion&space=8

Comment: @CedricArnould, I have voted your ticket and hope it could raise more Microsoft's attention. Since those are all we can here, you could mark this answer to give a right guidance. Thanks in advance, have a nice day!